# Let $f(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}$.If $f(n)=2047,$ then find the value of $n.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Let $f(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}$.If $f(n)=2047,$ then find the value of $n.$

---

$f(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{k}{2}+......+\sum_{k=n}^{n}\binom{k}{n}$
I am not able to simplify it further.Please help me.

Comment: Shouldnt it be $r=0$

Comment: This one is probably going to be easiest with some computer algebra software and guess and check. That double sum will get big fast so it won't take long.

Comment: HINT: $f(n) = 2^{n+1}-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will show you that $f(n) = 2^{n+1}-1$.
$$f(n) = \sum_{0 \le r \le k \le n} \binom{k}{r} = \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \sum_{r=0}^k \binom{k}{r} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = 2^{n+1}-1$$

So that $$2047 = 2^{n+1}-1$$
$$2^{n+1}= 2048 = 2^{11}$$
$$n+1=11$$
$$n=10$$

Comment: I do not understand how this comes $\sum_{0 \le r \le k \le n} \binom{k}{r} = \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \sum_{r=0}^k \binom{k}{r} \right) $?@Crostul

Comment: Yes: this is simply changing the order of summation.

Comment: It's simply another way to sum over the set of indices $\{ (r,k) \in \Bbb{N}^2: 0 \le r \le k \le n \}$. This set of indices can be written as $\{ (r,k)\in \Bbb{N}^2 : 0 \le r \le n , r \le k \le n \} = \{ (r,k) \in \Bbb{N}^2: 0 \le k \le n , 0 \le r \le k \}$. Try to draw this on paper, and I'm sure it will become clear.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$ $$f(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=r}^{n}\binom{k}{r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{r+1}=???$$